# Conditional PDO bindParam Update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm trying to do a conditional update but I seem to be having problems with binding the data with the statement.

function:

```
function updateEditor($email, $first, $last, $id){
global $DBH;
$response = false;
$upemail = "";
$upfirst = "";
$uplast = "";

$stmt = "SELECT memEmail, memFirst, memLast FROM MEMBER WHERE memID = :id";
try{
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($stmt);
    $STH->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $STH->execute();

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    if($row['memEmail'] != $email){ $upemail = $email;}
    if($row['memFirst'] != $first){ $upfirst = $first;}
    if($row['memLast'] != $last){ $uplast = $last;}

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "first";

}
$stmt .= "UPDATE MEMBER SET ";
if(!empty($upemail)){
    $stmt .= "memEmail = :memEmail";
    if(!empty($upfirst) || !empty($uplast)){
        $stmt .= ", ";
    }
}
if(!empty($upfirst)){
    $stmt .= "memFirst = :memFirst";
    if(!empty($uplast)){
        $stmt .= ", ";
    }
}
if(!empty($uplast)){
    $stmt .= "memLast = :memLast";
}
if(empty($upemail) && empty($upfirst) && empty($uplast)){
    return false;
}else{
    $stmt .= " WHERE memID = :id";
}

try{
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($stmt);
    if(!empty($upemail)){$STH->bindParam(':memEmail', $upemail);}else{$STH->bindParam(':memEmail', $row['memEmail']);}
    if(!empty($upfirst)){$STH->bindParam(':memFirst', $upfirst);}else{$STH->bindParam(':memFirst', $row['memFirst']);}
    if(!empty($uplast)){$STH->bindParam(':memLast', $uplast);}else{$STH->bindParam(':memLast', $row['memLast']);}
    $STH->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $STH->execute();

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $response = true;
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "second";
    $response = $e->getMessage() . "second";

}
return $response;
}
```

I have tried putting the variables into the statement, using `?`, and the code above so far. The error I keep getting is:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: sorry that was testing. the error is coming from the second `try` statement

Comment: You're setting the param in both if and else statement. But in the query you include the param only if it's not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
$stmt .= "UPDATE MEMBER SET ";
```

you append the UPDATE to the previous `$stmt` string. You'll end up with:

```
$stmt = "SELECT memEmail, memFirst, memLast FROM MEMBER WHERE memID = :idUPDATE MEMBER SET "; // and the rest
```

reulting in one identifier more (`:idUPDATE`).

Remove the `.` to start a new query in this string.

```
$stmt = "UPDATE MEMBER SET ";
```

Note:
You are making this way too complicated. Skip the checks for empty values, just update all columns when you update a dataset, you don't gain anything by checking what has changed and what hasn't first.

Comment: I put it without the `.` still same error. and I changed the name of the first `stmt` and am still getting same error

Comment: Well, echo `$stmt` before you prepare it and compare it with your binds.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Gerald Schneider answer, you are setting the param in both cases (if/else)

```
if(!empty($upemail)){$STH->bindParam(':memEmail', $upemail);}else{$STH->bindParam(':memEmail', $row['memEmail']);}
```

But are defining the parameters only in one case

```
if(!empty($upemail)){
    $stmt .= "memEmail = :memEmail";
    if(!empty($upfirst) || !empty($uplast)){
        $stmt .= ", ";
    }
}
if(!empty($upfirst)){
    $stmt .= "memFirst = :memFirst";
    if(!empty($uplast)){
        $stmt .= ", ";
    }
}
if(!empty($uplast)){
    $stmt .= "memLast = :memLast";
}
```

There's no else condition